# 227 Entering Passive Mode replay of FTPServer to ip address and port

Tags: java, string, ftp

i recived the replay message from FTPServer when i send the PASV command as following

227 Entering Passive Mode (159,153,197,77,194,82)

how would i get the ip address from this string replay message. and convert it to InternetAddress....

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`227 Entering Passive Mode (h1,h2,h3,h4,p1,p2)` is the syntax, h1-h4 are the 4 bytes of the ip address, p1 and p2 is a 2 byte port number, but i don't see how you'd convert that into an rsc822 internet address, which is in the `local@domain` form.
Oh and btw you can use `string.substring(27,string.length-2).split(",")` to get the params as seperate strings, then use `Byte.parseByte(string)` for each of the values